# Distribution of Fractional Part of $\log n$

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I am looking at the sequence $x_n = \{\log(n)\}$, where I am assuming (WLOG) that the base is $e$ and moreover $f:x\mapsto\{x\}$ takes $x$ to its fractional part.

I am wondering if it is true and possible to show that 
\begin{equation}
A=\bigg\{n:x_n \geqslant \frac{1}{2}\bigg\}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
B=\bigg\{n:x_n < \frac{1}{2}\bigg\}
\end{equation}
are both infinite. I believe [Weyl's criterion](http://math.rice.edu/~michael/teaching/426_Spr14/UDmod1A.pdf) says that $x_n$ isn't equidistributed along $(0,1)$, but then it doesn't seem possible that $\{\log(n)\}$ is eventually bounded above or below by $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence I am hoping to verify my intuition.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about considering a sequence of integers of the form $\lceil e^x +1\rceil$ (resp. $\lfloor e^x - 1\rfloor$) and via inequalities and maybe a Taylor expansion show that one will lead to elements in $A$, while the other in $B$?

Comment: Yes, $A$ and $B$ are both infinite since 1. $\log n\to\infty$ and 2. $\log(n+1)-\log n\to0$. Actually, properties 1. and 2. alone imply the stronger results that $\{x_n\,;\,n\in A\}$ is dense in $[0,\frac12]$ and that $\{x_n\,;\,n\in B\}$ is dense in $[\frac12,1]$. Nite that the natural densities of $A$ and $B$ are not equal but equal to $\frac{\sqrt{e}}{\sqrt{e}+1}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}+1}$ respectively.

Comment: @Did Thank you for the tip, yup $\log(n+1)-\log(n)\rightarrow 0$ does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

$\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ can be unequally distributed along $(0,1)$, yet there could still be infinitely many members in $A$ and $B$.  For example, the  sequence of random variables $$X_n = \begin{cases} U_n, & 3 \mid n \\ U_n+1/2, & 3 \not\mid n, \end{cases}, \quad U_n \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1/2)$$ is not equally distributed on $(0,1)$, but of course, $A$ and $B$ under your definitions would trivially be sets with infinitely many members.